# x11_init missing on OS X, even with Quartz installed

Tags: macos, x11

Hell, I'm trying to compile and link spice3f5 on OS X El Capitan.    I got it to compile, with a fair amount of tweaking of old-style C code, but now it won't link, it can't seem to find X11 .  I added /opt/X11 to the link options, but it's looking for all kinds of entry points that don't exist.  What's weirder, if I look at the X11 library with "nm", there are no such X11 entry points in it!.  Example:

**$  util/build gcc**

"_X11_Arc", referenced from:      _device in fte.a(display.o)

"_X11_Clear", referenced from:      _device in fte.a(display.o)

"_X11_Close", referenced from:      _device in fte.a(display.o)

"_X11_DefineColor", referenced from:      _device in fte.a(display.o)

"_X11_DefineLinestyle", referenced from:      _device in fte.a(display.o)
"_X11_DrawLine", referenced from:      _device in fte.a(display.o)

"_X11_Init", referenced from:      _device in fte.a(display.o)

"_X11_Input", referenced from:      _device in fte.a(display.o)

"_X11_NewViewport", referenced from:      _device in fte.a(display.o)

"_X11_SetColor", referenced from:      _device in fte.a(display.o)

"_X11_SetLinestyle", referenced from:      _device in fte.a(display.o)

"_X11_Text", referenced from:      _device in fte.a(display.o)

"_X11_Update", referenced from:      _device in fte.a(display.o)

Help?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a library...

Comment: Why don't you show the exact command which is producing the above output?

Comment: Ok, I added the build line, and explained some more.